# Delete Rows from a pandas dataframe if matching strings exceed a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a  dataframe given below:

```
ID   PROD   QTY   PRICE   NAME
1     G      2     120    "Yes"   
2     B      5     150    "Yes"
3     S      2     80     "Yes"
4     T      5     300    "Yes"
1     G     -2     120    "Yes"   
2     B     -5     150    "Yes"
3     S      2     80     "No"
4     T      5     300    "No"
1     G     -2     120    "No"   
2     B     -5     150    "No"
3     S      2     80     "No"
4     T      5     300    "No"
1     G     -2     120    "No"   
2     B     -5     150    "No"
```

I have looked many questions but most are for numerical values and was not able to found one that can solve problem given below,

I want to delete a row if a value in the last column matches more times than a certain number. For example in case of above dataframe as "Yes" is present more than five times so I want to keep only first five rows and delete others remaining rows containing "Yes". Same is the case for "No" in last column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The almighty `groupby` comes to the rescue -

```
df.groupby('NAME').head(5)

    ID PROD  QTY  PRICE NAME
0    1    G    2    120  Yes
1    2    B    5    150  Yes
2    3    S    2     80  Yes
3    4    T    5    300  Yes
4    1    G   -2    120  Yes
6    3    S    2     80   No
7    4    T    5    300   No
8    1    G   -2    120   No
9    2    B   -5    150   No
10   3    S    2     80   No
```

Comment: This is perfect!